# Objective-C run Code as root with AuthorizationCreate

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to run a few lines of code as root in my Cocoa-App.
I've tried to realize this in getting root privileges with AuthorizationCreate and releasing these privileges after running the code.

Problem is, I do not have root privileges in the //Run my code section and do not know why.

Hope someone can figure out why. 
Thanks!

```
   AuthorizationRef myAuthorizationRef;
OSStatus myStatus;

myStatus = AuthorizationCreate (NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment,
                                kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed , &myAuthorizationRef);
AuthorizationItem myItems[1];

myItems[0].name = kAuthorizationRightExecute;
myItems[0].valueLength = 0;
myItems[0].value = NULL;
myItems[0].flags = 0;

AuthorizationRights myRights;
myRights.count = sizeof (myItems) / sizeof (myItems[0]);
myRights.items = myItems;

AuthorizationFlags myFlags;
myFlags = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults |
kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed |
kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

myStatus = AuthorizationCopyRights (myAuthorizationRef, &myRights,
                                    kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, myFlags, NULL);

if (myStatus==errAuthorizationSuccess)
{

  //Run my Code


}

myStatus = AuthorizationFree (myAuthorizationRef, kAuthorizationFlagDestroyRights);
```

Comment: How do you know you don't have the proper rights?

Comment: Have you seen [this blog article about this](http://www.michaelvobrien.com/blog/2009/07/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-a-simple-example/)?

Comment: Also, I think Apple has a better, recommended way to make a Cocoa app do privileged tasks. This [other StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35532550/105539) talks about something similar.